# Operating system inside

Tags: c, unix, operating-system, system-calls

I have three questions which are causing me a lot of doubts:

1. If one thread in a program calls `fork()`, does the new process
   duplicate all threads, or is the new process single-threaded?
2. If a thread invokes `exec()`, will the program specified in the parameter
   to `exec()` replace the entire process including ALL the threads?
3. Are system calls preemptive? For example whether a process can be scheduled in middle of a system call?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by Question 3? A single execution context will always appear to execute sequentially, so what exactly do you have in mind?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I'm not sure what the OP wants to know. She's asking about "scheduling a process". I think some clarification will help in getting some useful answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `exec`, from `man execve`:

> All  threads  other than the calling thread are destroyed during an `execve()`.

From `man fork`:

> The child process is created with a single thread — the one that called `fork()`.

Answer (score 1):

W.r.t. #3: Yes, you can invoke a system call that directly or indirectly makes another thread ready to run. And if that thread has a greater priority than the current and the system is designed to schedule it right then, it can do so.